# Vba coding with if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format/fill a range in column P to a certain color when there is date format in column L cells and this word (Ready) is present in cells of column O. I tried this formula but so far, it hasn’t worked. See below.

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = days_ready

If ws.range("L3:L76").NumberFormat = "mm/did/yyyy" And ws.Range("O3:O76").Value = "Ready" Then 
    ws.Range("P3:P76").FormatConditions.Interior.Color = 2162853
End if
```

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

I tried a If statement with vba coding  but I got “method ‘range’ of object’_Worksheet’ failed” error.

Comment: You need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, note I have changed the `NumberFormat` test to `"mm/ddd/yyyy"`, I assume your original post had a typo.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rWork As Range, r As Range

Set ws = days_ready
Set rWork = ws.Range("L3:L76")

For Each r In rWork
    If r.NumberFormat = "mm/ddd/yyyy" And ws.Range("O" & r.Row).Value = "Ready" Then
        ws.Range("P" & r.Row).FormatConditions.Interior.Color = 2162853
    End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
Public Sub FillCells()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("days_ready")

Dim r As Range
Dim v As String
Dim i As Integer


Set r = Range("O3:O5")

For Each cell In r
v = cell.Value

i = cell.Row

If (v = "Ready") Then
ws.Cells(i, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If

Next

End Sub
```